# Different Views on Same Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that resembles the below:

| Date | Symbol | High | Med | Low | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-Jan-2021 | A | 0.3 | 0.2 | 0.1 | Comment on A |
| 01-Jan-2021 | B | 3 | 2 | 1 | Comment on B |

As you can see above, the comment applies to all prices (high, medium and low)

I now need to turn this into a melted dataframe without the comment, which I achieve as below:

```
df = df.melt(id_vars=['Date', 'Symbol'], value_vars=['High', 'Medium', 'Low'], var_name='Quote', value_name = 'Metric')
```

Giving:

| Date | Symbol | Quote | Metric |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-jan-21 | A | High | 0.3 |
| 01-jan-21 | A | Med | 0.2 |
| 01-jan-21 | A | Low | 0.1 |
| 01-jan-21 | B | High | 0.3 |
| 01-jan-21 | B | Med | 0.2 |
| 01-jan-21 | B | Low | 0.1 |

Where I'm struggling is I now want to apply the comment to each of the lines in the above melted view, giving:

| Date | Symbol | Quote | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-jan-21 | A | High | Comment on A |
| 01-jan-21 | A | Med | Comment on A |
| 01-jan-21 | A | Low | Comment on A |
| 01-jan-21 | B | High | Comment on B |
| 01-jan-21 | B | Med | Comment on B |
| 01-jan-21 | B | Low | Comment on B |

Note how the single comment for each symbol is now repeated for each Quote.  This is example only, there are a wider range of dates and quotes (i.e. several dates for each quote and more than just quotes A and B)

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So need add `Comment` to `id_vars` parameter?

```
df = df.melt(id_vars=['Date', 'Symbol','Comment'], 
             value_vars=['High', 'Medium', 'Low'], 
             var_name='Quote', 
             value_name = 'Metric')
```

Also if alla nother columns not defined in `id_vars` are used in `value_vars` is possible use:

```
df = df.melt(id_vars=['Date', 'Symbol','Comment'], 
             var_name='Quote', 
             value_name = 'Metric')
```